# Could not get the home page using code-igniter HMVC pattern

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, hmvc

I am facing one issue. I could not get the home page while using CodeIgniter HMVC pattern and the below error is coming.

> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

I am providing my code below.

**application/config/config.php:**

```
$config['modules_locations'] = array(
    APPPATH . 'modules/' => '../modules/',
);
```

**application/core/MY_Controller.php:**

```
<?php
 
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
 
/* load the MX_Router class */
require APPPATH . "third_party/MX/Controller.php";
 
/**
 * Description of my_controller
 *
 * @author https://roytuts.com
 */
class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {
 
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if (version_compare(CI_VERSION, '2.1.0', '<')) {
            $this->load->library('security');
        }
    }
 
}
 
/* End of file MY_Controller.php */
/* Location: ./application/core/MY_Controller.php */
```

**modules/site/controllers/site.php:**

```
<?php

(defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Description of site
 *
 * @author https://www.roytuts.com
 */
class Site extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }

}
```

**application/config/routes.php:**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'site';
```

Here I am using HMVC extension of CodeIgniter 3 but I could not found the simple page.

Comment: Have you tried without extending CI_Controller instead of extending MX_Controller ? but you have to create modular structure.
Exmple route : $route['user/dashboard']                                =       "user/Dashboard/userDashboard";

Comment: @BRjava : Actually I was learning from `https://www.roytuts.com/setup-hmvc-with-codeigniter-3/` link and as per this link its not working.

Comment: can you try without extending MX_Controller ?

Comment: @BRjava: you mean from  `class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller`  i need to remove `extends MX_Controller` ?

Comment: @BRjava : I tried but same issue.